# Protocol methods don't work

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I try to add UIGridView from here: https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView

In the difference of manual, I use storyboard. As written in manual, I extend UITableViewController by protocol UIGridViewDelegate, so I have this result:

```
class SmilesViewController: UITableViewController, UIGridViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @objc func gridView(grid: UIGridView!, widthForColumnAt columnIndex: CInt) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    @objc func gridView(grid: UIGridView!, heightForRowAt rowIndex: CInt) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    @objc func numberOfColumnsOfGridView(grid: UIGridView!) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    @objc func numberOfCellsOfGridView(grid: UIGridView!) -> Int {
        return 9
    }

    @objc func gridView(grid: UIGridView!, cellForRowAt rowIndex: CInt, andColumnAt columnIndex: CInt) -> UIGridViewCell! {
        var cellIdentifier: String = "smile_cell"

        var cell: UIGridViewCell? = grid.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UIGridViewCell
        if cell != nil {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SmilesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIGridViewCell
        }

        return cell!
    }

    /*@objc func gridView(grid: UIGridView!, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: CInt, andColumnAt columnIndex: CInt) {

    }*/
}
```

But breakpoints on the functions of protocol don't act. So I tried to add cutom class to my Table View and got this:

[image: Storyboard scene]

But anyway it doesn't work.

I newbie in swift and I don't have experience to translate xib-based application to storyboard application. Demo application from github works perfect. I don't understand the reason, why my app doesn't work. Is it obj-c porting problem or mistake in the storyboard?

And also, maybe somebody give me a link to better implementation of ios Grid

**Update**

Sample project has "uiGridViewDelegate" connection, in my project I cannot to connect it with my controller code
[image]

Comment: Do you set your object as the delegate of the grid view somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean in storyboard? Yes, SmilesController sets as SmilesViewController, and as pictured, UITableView sets as GridView

Comment: If you select the grid view in the storyboard and examine the Connections Inspector, does it show a `delegate` property?  If so, is it connected to the controller that implements the protocol?

Comment: There was some delegate connection, but I don't remember when I created it and where it goes. I look at sample project, there's GridView doesn't have "delegate" connection, but has "uiGridViewDelegate" connect. So I removed "delegate" and tried to add "uiGridViewDelegate". But I have fail. Could you tell me, please, how to see where connection goes. I didn't find answer in the Google. I think problem may will be resolved. I added picture with connection inspector of my project

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the project from the GitHub and the only difference that I can notice for now is. in the project the `dataSource` of the `UIGridView` is not connected to the `UIViewController` as you are doing. so remove that.

What is actually connected is the `uiGridViewDelegate`. not `dataSource` as your image show.

Image from GitHub Project:

[image]

Try that.

Comment: I just did the same before saw your question. Yes, it works! Thanks!